# Disk2vhd,convert my PC to Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: hyper-v, disk2vhd

Senario:

I have my development PC or Workstation with lot of applications like SQL Server,Visual Studio installed, and in-case my PC goes down then I have to go through the lengthy procedure of hooking and setting up a new development machine.Since we have a Hyper-V 2008 SP1 (not R2 yet) server with enough RAM,Can i :-

1.Use the Disk2vhd by systinternals and vhd my C: and D: and host in on Hyper-V and get it to Boot? (Windows XP SP3)

2.Will having bad sectors on D: drive halt the Disk2vhd making ?

3.Should I uninstall my current drivers before I do the Disk2vhd so that hyper-v does not cause a blue screen?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, as long as both are bootable drives to begin with. If you are referring to `D:` as being a data drive, you can do that too. Just check it off when making the disk in disk2vhd, then add a second hard disk in the VM settings.
2. It won't halt it, they are skipped over.
3. Don't worry about changing drivers, on first boot of the VM the hardware is detected and the appropriate drivers are installed if necessary.

Comment: let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hi John T. Just following up, I did the Disk2vhd of the C: drive (bootable)-win7e and created a new hyper-v machine with win2008r2,booted off changed pc name + reactivate win7.Well a strange thing was that my pc was raid and 600gb so the win7 or d2v showed the rest of the space as drives ...well worked (did not run sysprep)