# Convert Windows XP x32 physical machine to guest virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc, disk2vhd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disk2vhd,convert my PC to Hyper-V Virtual Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/73748/disk2vhd-convert-my-pc-to-hyper-v-virtual-machine)

I've just bought a machine running Windows 7 x64 Professional. I want to use this to run my old XP x32 installation as a virtual machine using Virtual PC.

My plan is to create images of the 2 current XP drives using [Disk2vhd](http://technet.Microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx). Then install these drive images in an XP virtual machine.

- Should this work?
- Will I need to activate XP on the virtual machine?
- Will 1 GB be enough to run the virtual machine (16 GB available on host)?
- Are there any other pitfalls of which I need to be aware?

Comment: If your license for XP came with the computer, you CANNOT do this.  That license is locked to the old computer (the one it was first installed on).

Answer (score 3):

> Should this work?

Yes, of course.

> Will I need to activate XP on the virtual machine?

Yes, you will.

> Will 1 GB be enough to run the virtual machine (16 GB available on host)?

Only you will be able to decide based on programs you use. Windows XP *will* run fine on 1GB.

> Are there any other pitfalls of which I need to be aware?

As you don't change your old system, just try. There shouldn't be any problems, but if so, all you lost are some cpu cycles and disk I/O.

Also think about using Virtual Box which is also free but in more active development.

Comment: Personally, out of 3 or 4 tries on a couple different computers, I've not had disk2VHD work yet for system disks. Ended up using VMWare converter and going over to a VMWare stack for those machines. So with Disk2VHD YMMV, but yeah it 'should work'.  :)